# External failure of law of excluded middle in Martin-Löf type theory

Tags: type-theory

Is there an explicit type $T$ in Martin-Löf type theory such that $(T\to \mathbf{0})\to\mathbf{0}$ has an explicit closed term and $T$ can be shown externally to not have closed terms?

Comment: What do you mean by a type or a term to be 'explicit'?

Comment: @ice1000 if you could write down the string defining it

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Take any $A$ type which cannot be proven or disproven in MLTT, necessarily by some external argument. Then $A \lor \lnot A$ is not provable but $\lnot (\lnot (A \lor \lnot A))$ is provable, because this is an intuitionistic tautology for all $A$. Reminder: $\lnot A$ is defined as $A \to \mathbf{0}$.

Some examples for types whose inhabitation is independent from basic intuitionistic MLTT:

- Function extensionality
- Uniqueness of identity proofs
- Parametricity (for given types)
- Law of excluded middle

Comment: Are all examples necessarily of your form?

Comment: Let $A$ be one of my examples, then take $A \lor \lnot A$ for your $T$.